# proper formatting in long fragments of code

Tags: ruby, formatting

if i have to use unless/if and blocks, code might get really long. This doesnt look nice at all, and my question is how to handle this kind of situation, what is the proper formatting, eg in this hipothetical case?

```
if some_array.each.all? {|argument| argument.method_one == @some_value} && another_array.method_two == @completely_different_value

    #
    #some stuff here
    #

end
```

Comment: set variables to the booleans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty ways to accomplish your task.

The most common way is to use backslashes as you do in shell prompt:

```
if some_array.each.all? { |argument| \
    argument.method_one == @some_value \
  } \
  && another_array.method_two == @completely_different_value \

 puts a
end
```

Also you may silently break the line at `dot`s (dot must be placed *at the end of the line* in Ruby < 1.9 or *at the beginning* of the next line as well in Ruby 1.9+.)

```
"foo bar baz".
  reverse.
  split.
  map(&:capitalize).
  join ' '
# ⇒ "Zab Rab Oof"
```

Comment: 'Avoid using {...} for multi-line blocks' from Ruby Guide Style https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: @megas This *is* in fact a one-line block. I reformat what was asked to be syntax-correct and placed on several lines. Using `do-end` clause there is fine _w/o trailing backslashes_.

Comment: I would totally use curlies here instead of do/end, curlies make it more clear you're still in the conditional. But I wouldn't use backslashes, none of these lines need it except for the third one because the `&&` is on the next line. But the `&&` could just be moved to the previous line and everything would work fine. Really, though, I'd just abstract the conditional into a local variable or a method.

Comment: @JoshuaCheek Sure the backslashes here are superfluous. But there was a snippet in the question, right? The question was how to split long line into short ones, right? So I took a line _given_ and inserted backslashes. Not that the result is the example of “how the code is to written,” but the question seems to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide it in several lines. I think this format is more easier to read

```
result1 = some_array.each.all? { |argument| argument.method_one == @some_value }
result2 = another_array.method_two == @completely_different_value
if result1 && result2
  #
  #some stuff here
  #
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend extracting the parts into variables

```
condition1 = some_array.each.all? do |argument|
  argument.method_one == @some_value
end

condition2 = another_array.method_two == @completely_different_value

if condition1 && condition2
    #
    # some stuff here
    #
end
```

or making the conditions into methods

```
def condition1?(arr)
  arr.some_array.each.all? do |argument|
    argument.method_one == @some_value
  end
end

def condition2?(arr)
  arr.method_two == @completely_different_value
end

if condition1?(some_array) && condition2?(another_array)
    #
    # some stuff here
    #
end
```

extracting into methods has the advantage that your code generally becomes easier to test.